# Logs not rolling at desired time(Log4j2)

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

**I want my solr-indexer logs to get rolled over every day at 12AM UTC, meaning that the .gz file should be created every day at 00:00:00UTC and it should contain all the logs of the previous day starting from 00:00:00UTC and ending somewhere at 23:59:59UTC.**

For example, the log(.gz)file created at 00:00:00UTC on 21st November should contain all the 24hr logs of 20th November.

This is how my log4j2 xml file looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO" packages="com.fidelis.k2.logging.filter">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log_path">/opt/k2/logs</Property>
        <Property name="log_pattern">%t - %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c:%L - %m%n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="rollingFile" fileName="${log_path}/solr_data_uploader.log"
                     filePattern="${log_path}/solr_data_uploader-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>${log_pattern}</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="false" timeUnit="days"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="15"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.fidelis.k2" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="rollingFile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I tried with modulate="true" as well, but it was not showing the logs for the whole day in the zip file.
Currently the log files(for some unknown reason) are getting created at 06:10UTC every day and it does not contain logs for the whole day.

Answer (score 0):

The rolling file appender uses the timezone in your `%d{...}` pattern to determine, when the day ends. The general form of the date pattern is:

```
%d{format specifiers}{timezone}
```

If the `timezone` parameter is missing, it defaults to the system timezone.

If you want to rotate base on UTC, just change:

```xml
<RollingFile name="rollingFile"
             fileName="${log_path}/solr_data_uploader.log"
             filePattern="${log_path}/solr_data_uploader-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
```

to

```xml
<RollingFile name="rollingFile"
             fileName="${log_path}/solr_data_uploader.log"
             filePattern="${log_path}/solr_data_uploader-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}{UTC}.log.gz">
```

Comment: Hi Piotr. I just checked my the default time of the ec2 instance on which this code is running. It is already in UTC timezone. Also, the filePattern in my code already has dd as the most specific time unit. 
Please let me know what else am I missing.

Comment: Java's timezone can be different. Try running `jshell` and evaluate `java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault()` or try adding `-Duser.timezone=UTC` to your JVM arguments.

Comment: I just found out this piece of code in our repo which(I guess) says that we are using UTC as our current timeZone:

public static String getDefaultTimeZone() {
        return FConstants.TIMEZONE_UTC;
    }

The file containing this code is named as DateUtil.java

Comment: You code might very well use that method, but my guess is that `ZoneId.systemDefault()` returns `America/Chicago`.